# is it possible to force users of older app versions to update?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Is it possible to remove older versions from the app stores and avoid users from using them? I did not include some framework that checks if there is an update, so my question is if there is something native from Google and/or Apple that enables me to mark older versions as deprecated or sth. like that.

I'm afraid there isn't something like that, but maybe someone knows a solution?

Comment: I don't think it is possible since both the package names are different. If you have control of older version of your app then you can send some notification to the user with new app link Or just placing the disclaimer in the old version for not supporting.:)

Comment: I think you need to add more details. What do you want it? If the problem is the vulnerability: to add validation on the server. If it is a local vulnerability, then it should not bother you.

Comment: Yhea, would be great to have some kind of store related SDK that would allow that. I'm facing the same need as you do with older release of one of my apps.

Answer (score 3):

You can still make an API call or an `httpUrlConnection` to get the latest version available, or check for this update on the google market if the user has it, and then redirect the user on the market in case of available update, preventing him to use the app if this case.

However if the user disconnect this solution won't work anymore. If you are not afraid of what can do the user offline, this solution work.

**Edit**: sorry, didn't see your app was released yet!

**So** I don't think it's possible then, especially for security reasons. And don't forget that many user don't have the google market ( blocked in china, sometimes replaced by the samsung store or another one, ... ).

Comment: my problem is that the versions are already out there, so I can't implement a check like this unfortunately

Comment: how would it be possible for the already distributed releases ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible then, especially for security. And don't forget that many user don't have the google market ( blocked in china, sometimes replaced by the samsung store or another one, ... ). I edited my post as I didnt see your app was yet released.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can do it in your app itself.

Just save `android:versionName` on first app initialization.

Then in each start, get the current version and check compare it with the last /saved one. If its same then ignore. If different then you can show one non cancelable dialog to force user to update the app.

To get app version:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;
```

I think its a friendly way for developers.

Comment: my problem is that the versions are already out there, so I can't implement a check like this unfortunately